# AngularJS formatting text in scope value in templateURL

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive `<some-directive ver="val"></some-directive>` that returns a `templateUrl` with a dynamic sentence based on ver value. I have been attempting to add a line-break in value so the text appears in two lines when embedded into the template, but `\r`and `\n` only add a space but not adding a new line.

```
directive('someDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            //based on scope or attrs customize the first reply
            var type=attrs.ver;
            switch(type) {
            case 'val1':
                scope.lm = { 
                    eng: 'This is my sentence that needs a break in the middle.',
                    cha: 'This is another sentence that needs a break in the middle.'
                };
              break;
            case 'val2':
                scope.lm = { 
                    eng: 'This is my sentence that needs a break in the middle.',
                    cha: 'This is another sentence that needs a break in the middle.'
                };
              break;
            default:
                scope.lm = { 
                    eng: 'This is my sentence that needs a break in the middle.',
                    cha: 'This is another sentence that needs a break in the middle.'
                };
            }
        },
        templateUrl : 'content/excerpts/some-template.html'

    }
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you
AJG

Comment: use <br/> some back in the past i read that /r &/n are not parsed

Comment: for translation you can use angular-translation or like. see http://angular-translate.github.io/

Comment: @Tek `<br />` will not display as expected in the DOM if used during `link` as DOM compilation would've already happened. Either rely on `ng-bind-html` or you could use the `$compile` service inside `link` to get your line breaks.

Comment: @miqid using `link` for DOM manipulation is not appropriate. For DOM manipulation is used `compile` at first place...